# Wordpress - insert Ajax-based login form upon link click event

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to get help with a WordPress staging site located at:

http://sbane39-beta.knowarecms.net.

I'm trying to get an existing Ajax-based login form to display when a non-logged-in user clicks an 'Add To Cart' button in my installation of the Event Espresso event management plugin.

An Ajax-based login form already exists, and functions properly when a user clicks the "Member Log In" button located just below the scrolling slideshow in the header of the page.

However, a copy of the form that is should be called when an "Add To Cart" button (in the main nav bar, click Events, All Events to see a list of available events) is clicked doesn't appear - instead, the default behavior of the link fires, which is a redirection to the Event Espresso shopping cart with the specific event added to it.

In both cases, the click event is being handled by the script at :

http://sbane39-beta.knowarecms.net/wp-content/themes/sbanenew/js/ajax-login-script.js.

In the case of the "Member Log In" button, the handler function is:

```
$("a[title='memberlogin']").on('click', function(e){...}
```

For the "Add to Cart" buttons, the handler function is:

```
$("a[id^='cart_link_']").on('click', function(e){...}
```

When debugging the later, I can see that the function is being called on the click event, but for some reason preventDefault action isn't working to stop execution.

I added the return false statement to stop propagation, but with no luck.

My JS debugging skills aren't good enough to see why this is happening. Hopefully this forum is the appropriate place to seek help, so TIA for any guidance.

In response to brybott's request, here's the (modified) code with the return false statement moved:

```
$("a[id^='cart_link_']").on('click', function(e){ //When an Add To Cart button is clicked...        
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the default action
    //$addToCartURL = $(this).attr('href');
    //display event login form only to logged out users
    jQuery.post(ajax_login_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if(response == 'yes') {
            //alert('You are already logged in');
        } else {
            $formLoginEvent.fadeIn(1000);//Fade the form in
            $('form#login_event a.close').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('form#login_event').fadeOut(1000);
            });
            return false; //stop propagation
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed one thing in your code..

```
$("a[id^='cart_link_']").on('click', function(e){ //When an Add To Cart button is clicked...        
    //$addToCartURL = $(this).attr('href');
    //display event login form only to logged out users
    jQuery.post(ajax_login_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if(response == 'yes') {
            //alert('You are already logged in');
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();//prevent the default action
            return false; //stop propagation
            $formLoginEvent.fadeIn(1000);//Fade the form in
            $('form#login_event a.close').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('form#login_event').fadeOut(1000);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

When you return a function, in your case you `return false; //stop propagation`, no lines that come after the return statement run. So, in your case, fading the form in will never happen. Try dropping the `return false;` line down to the end of your else statement and see if it works.

Comment: Duh - missed that one...moving the return statement did allow the form to 'fade' in. However, the default action of the link (a redirection) still occurred immediately after the form appeared. I tried copying & moving the e.preventDefault() statement to the first line of the function, but that didn't stop the redirection either. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So brybott was correct in stating that the return false statement was misplaced. I needed to move it outside the jQuery.post call, to the last line of the click() handler function - doing that causes the form to display, and keeps the redirection from occuring.